# Do I have to change anything in the source code when I upgrade to a higher CCU in photon?

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, server, cloud, photon

We have a project in Unity3d and it uses 20 CCU. We wanted to upgrade to a higher CCU in photon, do we have to change anything in it's source code or if we buy an upgrade in Photon we can leave the source code as it is? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no change in the code necessary. Just upgrade the Subscription of the appid (you need access to that account) from 20CCU (free) to 100CCU (one-time fee) or 500CCU and more (monthly fee).